# sql table trigger

Tags: sql, database-trigger

I need to write a table trigger and I've never done this before. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. Every time an order is placed with $0, I need the payment type to be set to 100. I run the below query manually, however it would be great if this was processed automatically.

```
UPDATE tblPay
SET lngPayTypeID = '100'
WHERE     (lngFloatID IN (14171)) AND (dateWebDate > '5/25/18 6:00PM')
          AND (curTender = '0')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using!  Trigger syntax depends on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the trigger `SetPayment` on table `tblPlay`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[SetPayment] 
   ON  [dbo].[tblPlay] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 

DECLARE
    @lngFloatID float,
    @curTender decimal

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        @lngFloatID = lngFloatID,
        @curTender = curTender          
    FROM
        inserted

    IF (@curTender = 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE
            tblPay
        SET
            lngPayTypeID = '100'
        WHERE
            lngFloatID = @lngFloatID
    END
END
```

When a record with `curTender = 0` is inserted, it will get its `lngFloatID` and set its `lngPayTypeID` to `100`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps a lot.